# why while installing mysql version 8 i get apt repository problem?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, apt

When I try to install mysql verison 8 on ubuntu server (16.04) according to [mysql apt repository documentations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/), after config of my need in dpkg command a file named **mysql.list** is made in this directory:
**/etc/apt/sources.list.d** which prevents apt to update and i get this error running command

> sudo apt-get update
>   :

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:3 http://compute.ipeserver.com.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://compute.ipeserver.com.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://compute.ipeserver.com.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease [5,309 B]
Err:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 331 kB in 2s (114 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

when i remove mysql.list file. the issue is solved. So I can't install mysql verison 8 on my server.